# Iterate over an Array of Symbols

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, symbols

I´d like to ask, if it´s possible to somehow iterate over an Array of Symbols.
I have this code:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from "react";

import { bemClassNames } from "@multiweb/reactUtils";

export type TabsProps = {
  children: any;
}

export const Tabs: FunctionComponent<TabsProps> = ({
  children
}) => {
  const classNames = bemClassNames("tabs-component");

  const tabs = children;

  const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleTabClick = (tabIndex: number) => {
    setActiveTabIndex(tabIndex === activeTabIndex ? activeTabIndex : tabIndex);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classNames()} role="tabpanel">
      <ul className={classNames("tabs-nav")}>
        {tabs.map((child: any, index: number) => {
          return React.cloneElement(child, {
            tabIndex: index,
            onClick: handleTabClick,
            isActive: index === activeTabIndex
          });
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get this error: TypeError: tabs.map is not a function.

So I suggest, that I need some method to iterate over an Array of Symbols or transform Symbols to Strings for example.
Would you know anybody, how to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe it's because tabs is not storing as an array. check the type of tabs

Comment: `React.Children(tabs).map`

Answer (score 0):

Please use React.Children.map for iteration
See example:

```
        <div>
        {React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => {          
          return child
        })}
      </div>
```

P.S. There is no special method for iteration over the array of symbols. You can just use map, reduce, forEach ...

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely the correct one solution. But now, tabIndex, onClick, isActive props are not passed down to lower component. In lower component, when I do console.log(tabIndex), it returns "undefined".

Comment: Sorry , it was just an example. You still should use React.cloneElement and pass down the props, exactly as you did it in your example